# how to use reflection to determine whether an Interface has a default method?

Tags: java

I'm like to figure out which methods in an Interface has a default method.

For example, in java.util.Collection, `stream()` has a default method. How would one go about programmatically finding that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the methods from an interface from its `Class<?>.getMethods()`: `myInterface.getMethods()`.

Each of those `Method` objects has a function `isDefault()`: `thisMethod.isDefault()`.